# Ionic - changing default colours

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I have an ionic project (ionic library version 1.3).  I am trying to change the default colour of "positive".

I have followed the instructions available in that I have added sass to my project using the command:

```
$ ionic setup sass
```

I have then accessed the file

*myapp*/scss/ionic.app.scss

as a very simple example I have added a value for positive that I would expect to change the colour to #111111:

```
/*
To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
in ionic's _variables.scss file.

For example, you might change some of the default colors:

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
*/


$positive:                        #222222 !default;
```

I am then running ionic serve, but seeing no change.

Any ideas on what this might be?... is my library too old... is there a reason it is not picking up the change?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this *command* from `CLI`:

```
gulp sass
```